# Schedule for turning phone on and off

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, schedule, mobile-phones

[This](http://privileg.cn/en/review/21-sm1review.html) phone have something very useful. That is his option to schedule power on and off.

> Another useful application standard, well hidden in submenus is
>   Schedule Power On / Off, which can set the phone to power on and power
>   off automatically at a certain time, and also at fixed days of the
>   week.

But how can I check programmatic-ally if the phone have schedule option ?, Is it possible to check this at all ?, or maybe even change the time programmatic-ally ...

I meet scheduling for a first time in the specifications of an android phone, I hope this will become standard cause it is really useful option(at least for me).

Edit:(this phone is not android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is manufacturer dependent, I found android phone named 'privileged' that have this option but no HTC phone have this option for scheduling , son generally this not android dependent feature it depends from the manufacturer and there is no handy api for this